# Why does the integer overflow in fscanf function

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define EMPTY '-'
#define HUMAN 'H'
#define ZOMBIE 'Z'

// Function Prototypes
char** read_map_from_txt(const char* filename, int *width, int *height);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int width, height;
    char *filename[50] = argv[0];
    char **grid = read_map_from_txt(filename, &width, &height);

    return 0
}

char** read_map_from_txt(const char* filenamee, int *width, int *height) {
    // This function should read width and height from the given filename and assign these values to the pointers given.
    // It also should allocate the memory for the grid and return a pointer for grid.
    // Write your code below
    //
    char filename[30] = "maps/map_1.txt";
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
    char line[100];

    *width = fscanf(file, "%d", width);
    printf("w - %d\n", width);
    *height = fscanf(file, "%d", height);
    printf("h - %s\n", height);

    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) != NULL) {
        printf("%s", line);
    }


    fclose(file);
    return NULL;
}
```

Basically, there are 2 numbers in the first two lines of the file what looks like this:
3
3
....(other info in the file)

and I am trying to extract them, however I can't assign them to the width and height variables, the ouput comes out like (rn only w and h matter)

```
w - -437801428
h -

-----
-H---
-ZH--
```

What am I doing wrong in here?

btw ignore the filename argument in the function arguments, and the main function, I am just doing that for testing

Comment: Whatever is `char *filename[50] = argv[0];` intending?

Comment: `*width = fscanf(file, "%d", width);` isn't correct. `fscanf` returns the number of items converted, not the value of any of them. You're not checking if the file is open either.

Comment: `*width = fscanf(file, "%d", width);` Why do you overwrite the converted input value with the return value of `fscanf` function? They are very different values. Read the manpage to see what the function returns. Use `int status = fscanf(...` instead and check if `status == 1` for a successful read before you use `width` and `height`

Comment: Another problem you'll have is [scanf() leaves the newline character in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-newline-character-in-the-buffer) so the first line read after the fscanf will be empty.

Comment: See e.g. [this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value).

Comment: Also both `printf("w - %d\n", width)` *and* `printf("h - %s\n", height)` are incorrect, but for different reasons. A decent compiler should have emitted warnings for that, and if yours didn't then enable more warnings when building.

Comment: but I used the fscanf function with other variables to write ints from the same file and it worked
`
int i, j;

   fscanf (file, "%d", &i);
 fscanf (file, "%d", &j);
   while (!feof (file))
     {
        printf ("%d ", i);
        fscanf (file, "%d", &i);
     }

 printf("%d, %d\n", i, j);
`

Comment: Surprising amount of errors for so few lines of code. You should read [Why is “while( !feof(file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong) as well based on the code in the comment.

Comment: Regarding `while (!feof (file))`, please read [Why is “while( !feof(file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong)

Comment: And in your comment where you have `fscanf (file, "%d", &i)`, note that there's an important difference from the usage in the question.... In `fscanf (file, "%d", &i)` you don't do `i = fscanf (file, "%d", &i)` (which is wrong).

Answer (score 0):

1. `argv[0]` is usually the name of the binary being executed.  Perhaps you mean `argv[1]`?  You want to check `argc` before accessing `argv[1]`:

```
if(argc != 2) {
  // handle missing argument
}
```

2. `char *filename[50] = argv[0];` is an error.  Either use an initializer list:

```
char *filename[50] = { argv[1] };
```

or perhaps you meant a string instead of an array of 50 pointers;

```
#define MAX_PATH_LEN 49
// ...
char filename[MAX_PATH_LEN+1];
if(strlen(argv[1]) < MAX_PATH_LEN)
   strcpy(filename, argv[1]);
```

Or punt on the copy and pass `argv[1]` as is:

```
char **grid = read_map_from_txt(argv[1], &width, &height);
```

3. You have a typo in the argument `filenamee` (compared to the declaration).  Once you fix that you probably want to eliminate the variable `filename`.
4. Always check the return value of `fopen()`:

```
FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
if(!file) {
   // handle error
}
```

5. You call `fscanf()` incorrectly.  It returns the number of input items that were successfully read so it should be:

```
    int rv = fscanf(file, "%d", width);
    if(rv != 1) {
       // handle fscanf failing
    }
```

6. Incorrect type in format when reading height which should `%d` not `%s`.
7. You probably want to eliminate the space after the height value from example input.

Here is what you end up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void read_map_from_txt(const char* filename, int *width, int *height) {
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if(!file) {
        perror(filename);
        return;
    }
    if(fscanf(file, "%d", width) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to read width\n");
        goto err;
    }
    printf("w - %d\n", *width);

    if(fscanf(file, "%d", height) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to read height\n");
        goto err;
    }
    printf("h - %d\n", *height);
    char ch;
    if(fscanf(file, "%c", &ch) != 1 || ch != ' ') {
        fprintf(stderr, "separator missing\n");
        goto err;
    }
    char line[100];
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
        printf("%s", line);
    }
err:
    fclose(file);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if(argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "path missing\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int width;
    int height;
    read_map_from_txt(argv[1], &width, &height);
}
```

and with the input file maps_1.txt as (changed height to ensure different values are read):

```
3 4 other info
```

and example run outputs:

```
w - 3
h - 4
other info
```